# Как при наведении анимировать элемент, который в структуре находится выше?

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation

Как средствами CSS сделать так, чтобы при наведении на кнопку, менять стили для иконки?

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <div><i class="icon"></i></div>
    <h3>Some title</h3>
    <p>Some description</p>
    <a class="btn">Click on me!</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn:hover {
    background-color: skyblue;
}
/* И возможно ли это вообще? */
.btn:hover ? .icon {
    color: skyblue;
}
```

Comment: нет, но можно сделать `.icon` дочерним или псевдо элементом `.btn` и при помощи позиционирования переместить куда надо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, да, средствами CSS обратиться к вышестоящему элементу нельзя. Однако можно воспользоваться полезным свойством `order` при `display: flex` при помощи которого можно визуально изменить порядок отображения элементов. Таким образом, в структуре иконка находится ниже и к ней можно обратиться при помощи операторов `+` или `~`, но на странице показывается в самом верху. Такие дела. Может, кому пригодится.

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: whitesmoke;
}
.icon-wrapper {
  order: -1;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.icon::before {
  content: "\2764";
  font-style: normal;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn {
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background: skyblue;
}
.btn:hover + .icon-wrapper {
  color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <h3>Some title</h3>
  <p>Some description</p>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Click on me!</a>
  <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="icon"></i></div>
</div>
```