# Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на Подпункт 2.1 подсвечивался еще Пункт 2 в маркированном списке?

Tags: css, html5

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать с помощью **css**, чтоб при наведении на Подпункт 2.1 подсвечивался еще Пункт 2?

Вот код:

```
<style>
    ul > li > a:hover {
        color: red;
    } 
</style>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Пункт 1.</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Пункт 2.</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Подпункт 2.1.</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Подпункт 2.2.</a></li>          
                <li><a href="">Подпункт 2.3.</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <li><a href="">Пункт 3.</a></li>
</ul>
```

Спасибо заранее)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344140/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b5/1347557#1347557

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите задать стили для parent в зависимости от стилей ребенка.
Это можно сделать с помощью псевдокласса :has

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Есть правда небольшая проблема - сейчас он не поддерживается ни в одном из браузеров.

Видео как он работает:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJ1XMcwys48

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить класс родителю и сделать что-то такое..

```css
ul>li>a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.p2:hover {
  color: red;
}
.p2:hover ul:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 1.</a></li>
  <li class='p2'><a href="">Пункт 2.</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Подпункт 2.1.</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Подпункт 2.2.</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Подпункт 2.3.</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 3.</a></li>
</ul>
```