# Полноэкранное меню исключительно на HTML и CSS/SCSS/SASS

Tags: html, css, sass, scss

Хотел создать полноэкранное меню исключительно на HTML и CSS/SCSS/SASS. Принцип понимаю, но где-то ошибаюсь в реализации: совершенно не работает checkbox, регулирующий отображение блока полноэкранного меню.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    div {
      background-color: black;
      overflow: hidden;
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    input {
      visibility: visible;
      z-index: 3;
    }
    
    input:checked~div {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <!-- Полноэкранный блок -->
    <input type="checkbox">
    <!-- Добавляю кнопку для изменения отображения полноэкранного блока -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input:checked ~ div` - так не получится. Решение проблемы я уже приводил [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344140/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5).

Если вкратце, то обратиться к вышестоящему элементу нельзя.