# Почему не работает свойство hover?

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Вот мой код, я хочу сделать подчеркивание при наведении на input.

```
.form_field_container::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: red;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 10s;
    width: 10px;
}

.form_input:hover .form_field_container::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```
.form_field_container:hover::after{}
```

Если сделать after при наведении на сам элемент, который нужно подчеркнуть, то все работает, а если сделать `.form_input:hover .form_field_container::after`, то почему-то свойство перестает применяться

HTML

```
<div class="form_field_container" style="margin-bottom: 22px">
                <span class="enter_label">Логин</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Введите ваш логин или электронную почту" 
                name="login" class="form_input login_input">

</div>
```

Comment: Нужно поменять местами .form_field_container::after  
 .form_input:hover {
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: @Arcadiy, Что именно нужно поменять местами?

Comment: я же написал как надо попробовать, я с телефона проверить не могу, только совет

Comment: @Arcadiy, не работает(

Comment: @Тв0р0бушек, Вы знаете почему стили называют каскадными?

Comment: @UModeL, потому что стили могут быть применены в разных местах

Comment: @Тв0р0бушек, нет, это неверно. Называются они так, потому что идут по ниспадающей - сначала родитель, потом ребёнок. А Вы пытаетесь поставить ребёнка вперёд, чтобы он "рулил" родителем.

Comment: @UModeL, Что тогда нужно поменять? У меня уже нет вариантов

Comment: @UModeL, что здесь ребенок, а что родитель тогда?

Comment: @Тв0р0бушек, `.form_field_container` - родитель, `.form_input` - ребёнок.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142415/discussion-between-00-and-umodel).

Comment: @UModeL, а как мне быть в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже было верно подмечено в комментариях, CSS не позволяет обращаться к родителям и вышестоящим элементам (пример, [мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344140/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b5)), поэтому нужно либо менять логику, либо использовать JavaScript.

```css
body {
  max-width: 15rem;
}

.mb-2 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.form-group input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
}
.form-group:hover input,
.form-group input:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group mb-2">
  <label class="form-label" for="txtLogin">Login</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtLogin" placeholder="ivan@mail.ru">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label" for="txtPassword">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPassword" placeholder="12345678">
</div>
```